# When to use three-part column references in SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Firstly, apologies if this is in the wrong section, or the wrong style.  Hunted for this answer for a while, to no avail.

Imagine you have a (sample) SQL query in SQL 2014 -

```
SELECT
  dbo.Users.Surname,
  dbo.Accounts.Type
FROM
  dbo.Users
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Accounts
ON (dbo.Users.Id = dbo.Accounts.Id)
```

Up until now, this is the format I've been using - fully qualifying the table objects with [schema].[tablename].[column].

However, looking at the [SQL 2014 Deprecated Database Engine Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx), it says that this style is no longer standard -

> Two-part names is the standard-compliant behavior.

After digging around for a while, I found the [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms177563.aspx), where it says -

> To avoid name resolution errors, we recommend specifying the schema name whenever you specify a schema-scoped object.

So I'm a little confused as to how my little code snippet should be written.  Should I only use the schema when referencing the tables, but when referring to columns, skip the schema and just use the table names?  Or is it assuming all table objects should have an alias?

Again, apologies for the potential subjectivity of this question.  But essentially I'm asking about how to write SQL that does not use a deprecated feature of SQL 2014, but still reads well when joining multiple tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says that the deprecated feature applies to referencing columns, not tables.
To clarify imagine two statements:

```
SELECT dbo.Orders.ID FROM dbo.Orders
```

and

```
SELECT Orders.ID FROM dbo.Orders
```

The first is deprecated, not the last.

> To avoid name resolution errors, we recommend specifying the schema
>   name whenever you specify a schema-scoped object.

This applies to default schema of user. If user has default schema say 'Person' and two tables with the same name 'dbo.Persons', 'Person.Persons' exist in the database, then if that user executes:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
```

he will get results from table in Person schema, even if he did want data from dbo.

So the actual answer is:

Use

```
SELECT Orders.ID FROM dbo.Orders
```